# Sum(if) array in Excel 2013 for a range of columns

Tags: arrays, excel

I have a matrix in Excel with a "Type" in column A and consecutive dates across Row 1.

On each day for each type, the result is either 1 or zero.

My goal is to use a Sum(if) array to sum the values for a particular type for a date range by inputting a start date value in B9 and an end date value in B10 for a specified type ("A", "B", "C") in B8.

Here is the function I've started: {=SUM((A2:A4=B8)*(IF(B1:F1=B9,B2:F4)))}

I'm having difficulty making the function assess the range specified in B9 and B10. Also, you should know that I've used numbers for the day, so use "4" in place of ie 2/4/2015.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should help:

```
=SUMIFS(OFFSET(A1,MATCH(B8,A2:A4,0),1,1,5),B1:F1,">=" & B9,B1:F1,"<=" & B10)
```

The last parameter in `OFFSET` function (5) is number of columns in the sum (if the dates are in B1:F1, then it's 5)

Comment: What if I have more criteria than "Type", such as "Location" = or(1,2,3)? So, each type can be at more than one location.

Comment: I suppose `SUMPRODUCT` could help, but it's hard to suggest anything without data layout

Comment: Let's change the scenario a bit: Column A is Location (1,2,3), Column B is Employee (A, B, C), Column C is Shift (Morning, Afternoon), Columns D through H with 1 or zero values (1=employee scheduled to work, 0=employee not scheduled to work).

Comment: Then the formula would look something like: `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A4=B7)*(B2:B4=B8)*(C2:C4=B9)*(D1:H1>=B10)*(D1:H1<=B11),D2:H4)`, but I think it's another question, so if you need details, please mark accept my answer and post a separate question with detailed layout of data.

Comment: Actually, that was an easy fix to my problem. Thanks!